# Background Image for UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uitextview

I am having trouble implementing a background image for a UITextView. The problem I am having is that the actual Text is of an unknown size and the background image scrolls and then becomes white screen. How can I have the background image be the same size of the textView? I have the background image set via Storyboard and add subviews to the textView via code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [resizableImageWithCapInsets:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets%3a) to "stretch" your image to be as big as your TextView.

Comment: well the image has a Logo that is text, so will the logo be stretched as well?

Comment: Yes, it will be stretched, too. In this case, try using 2 images ... one with the background (which you'll stretch as per my first answer) and an image with the logo on top of it.

This should do the trick.