# UITextView background image is scrolling for multiple lines

Tags: swift, uitextview, background-image, swift4

I have created extension for UITextView, where I set image to the textview using below code.

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: ....)
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "textarea.png")
self.addSubview(backgroundImage)
self.sendSubview(toBack: backgroundImage)
```

At start it looks fine as showing below image (left side), however as I add multi-line text, image also starts scrolling (right side), which is incorrect.

[image]

Any idea how to make image fixed as it is?

Comment: any reason for downvote?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687258/background-image-for-uitextview
Try this.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri : Thanks, I did with the proper way. Posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what I did

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame:  ....)
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "textarea.png")
mainView.insertSubview(backgroundImage, belowSubview: self)
```

`mainView` is nothing but the main view (self.view) of view controller.

This is like we are ***not going to add backgroundImage in the subview of textview, instead we will be adding in the mainview (self.view)***.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:
A container UIView contains background UIImageView and TextView(with clear background color).